# C++ circular template dependency between Producer and Consumer in callback

Tags: c++, templates

I am designing two classes which encapsulate a producer and consumer. One class does single-thread processing, the other (not shown here) two threads.

The producer and consumer are passed to each 'threading class' by template parameters.

`*this` is passed to the producer to enable a callback upon each message:

```
template<class PRODUCER, class CONSUMER>
class SingleThread
{
    SingleThread() : _prod(*this){}

    void processMessage(const char* message, int len)
    {
        int d = _cons.doSomething(message, len);
        // Code omitted
    }

    PRODUCER<SingleThread<>> _prod;  //  Cyclical dependency
    CONSUMER _cons;
};
```

Each producer receives the threading class as a callback via template parameter:

```
template<class THREADING_CALLBACK>
class Producer
{
    Producer(THREADING_CALLBACK& cb) : _cb(cb){}

    // A lot of code omitted

    void receiveMessage(const char* message, int len)
    {
        _cb.processMessage(message, len);
    }

    THREADING_CALLBACK& _cb;
};
```

but I have a problem with circular template dependency. `SingleThread` takes `Producer` as a template parameter but `Producer` requires  `SingleThread`:

```
SingleThread<Producer<SingleThread<Producer<....>, Consumer>, Consumer>
```

How should I (re)structure this design?

Comment: Extract one or both of single thread and producer into interface classes that the actual class derives from.

Comment: Any cyclic dependency is indication that some abstraction should be extracted. In your case `SingleThread` should be split into `SingleThread` and `Consumer`.

Comment: @AndyG I wish for the clients to use the threading class like: SingleThread<Producer, Consumer>. Would the suggested abstraction still allow clients to declare like this?

Comment: @user997112:  `SingleThread` will derive from `IProcessMessage` and `Producer` will derive from `IReceiveMessage`. `SingleThread` won't use `Producer` directly, rather than `IReceiveMessage`. `Producer` wo't use `SingleThread` directly, rather than `IProcessMessage`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can omit the template arguments:

```
template<class THREADING_CALLBACK>
class Producer
{
public:
    Producer(THREADING_CALLBACK& cb) : _cb(cb){}

    void receiveMessage(const char* message, int len)
    {
        _cb.processMessage(message, len);
    }

    THREADING_CALLBACK& _cb;
};

template<template <class> class PRODUCER, class CONSUMER>
class SingleThread
{
public:
    SingleThread() : _prod(*this){}

    void processMessage(const char* message, int len)
    {
        // Code omitted
    }

    PRODUCER<SingleThread> _prod;
    CONSUMER _cons;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How would SingleThread be instantiated- SingleThread<Consumer, Producer>? I ask because there's no comma after '<class>'

Comment: `template <template <class> class PRODUCER>` is the correct syntax for template template arguements (your code was buggy). You can add the CONSUMER template parameter by writing: `template<template <class> class PRODUCER, class CONSUMER>` (I removed `class CONSUMER` only to make my example compileable).

Comment: @user997112 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name # Current instantiation

Comment: @user997112 I adjusted my post.

Answer (score 1):

You probably dont have requirement that producer knows about callback more than it looks like functor.

```
using THREADING_CALLBACK = std::function<void(const char* message, int len)>;
```

This way, Producer does not need to take THREADING_CALLBACK as template parameter.

```
class Producer
{
  public:
  Producer(THREADING_CALLBACK& cb) : _cb(cb){}

  void receiveMessage(const char* message, int len)
  {
    _cb(message, len);
  }

  THREADING_CALLBACK _cb;
};
```

Comment: I mentioned this in another comment but I wanted to avoid run-time mechanisms because the callback destination doesn't change. For example, polymorphism is ideal when the subtype is constantly changing. However, in this situation everything is known at compile time.

Comment: It is clear that you cant have two types Producer that is parameterized by Callback and at same time Callback parameterized by Producer. You can have at most  one out of two and You need to choose which one.

Answer (score 0):

As a framing challenge, as written the producer has no business knowing the implementation of the threading callback.

The callback is just a sink for some data.

Second, make it a value-type rather than a reference; it can internally do reference semantics if it likes.

```
template<class DATA_SINK>
class Producer
{
public:
    Producer(DATA_SINK cb) : _cb(cb){}

    void receiveMessage(const char* message, int len)
    {
        _cb(message, len);
    }

    DATA_SINK _cb;
};
```

we now see that the interface of `DATA_SINK` is `void(C-style string, length)`, aka `std::string_view`.

```
    void receiveMessage(std::string_view msg)
    {
        _cb(msg);
    }
```

now, the question is, how much overhead is there in an indirect call here, compared to your workloads?

```
class Producer
{
public:
    Producer(std::function<void(std::string_view)> cb) : _cb(cb){}

    void receiveMessage(const char* message, int len)
    {
        _cb(message, len);
    }

    std::function<void(std::string_view)> _cb;
};
```

we now have decoupled the `Producer` from what consumes its data.
`SingleThread`, because it owns the producer, still gets the template argumetn.

```
template<class PRODUCER, class CONSUMER>
class SingleThread
{
    SingleThread() : _prod([this](std::string_view sv){
      processMessage(sv);
    }){}

    void processMessage(std::string_view sv)
    {
        int d = _cons.doSomething(sv);
        // Code omitted
    }

    PRODUCER _prod;
    CONSUMER _cons;
};
```

dependency is now removed.  We can continue to tear apart dependencies in a similar way if we want.

You'll see above that I embedded the "pointer semantics" of the data-sink in the producer into the callback I installed;

```
    [this](std::string_view sv){
      processMessage(sv);
    }
```

here I store a pointer to the state of the callback, while `Producer` stores an actual value.

A side benefit to this strategy is that it produces a nice point where we can mock the API that `Producer` communicates with.

The cost of bouncing through a `std::function` is not zero, but it isn't high unless you are doing something like calling it for every pixel on a HD image at 60 FPS.

Comment: It's not so much the performance cost, it's the fact using run-time dereferencing implies the callback destination can change at run-time, whereas templates tells the reader "I'm not changing at runtime", if you see what I mean?

Comment: @user997112 It could still change at runtime; the type of the thing you are calling can dispatch it in an arbitrary way.  But you can also just make the `std::function` `const` to say "this doesn't change after construction".  Making code tightly coupled has a **cost** that grows with the size of your code base; to deal with tightly coupled code, you have to have the entire code base in your head at the same time.  Making code loosely coupled is required for human beings to build and maintain complex software with any kind of reliability.

Comment: "It is none of the producers business what happens to those messages" is a highly valuable and important simplification to how the producer works.